# Exception creating an App Domain in NUnit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, plugins, nunit, appdomain

I’ve written a plugin library that searches a directory for assemblies which export implementations of a given interface. It does this by loading all assemblies into a temporary app domain in a reflection only context and searching through the exported types. The temporary app domain is then unloaded, the assemblies of interest are loaded into the default app domain and objects of the found types are then instantiated for use through the searched-for interface.

I'm trying to write some unit tests for this process using NUnit, but I'm getting a FileNotFoundException only in the unit tests, when trying to wire up the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event. Here's a bare-bones example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnitAppDomains
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void NUnitTest()
        {
            var ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("someName");

            // this next line throws a FileNotFoundException, complaining about not being 
            // able to find the test assembly itself... o.O
            ad.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += SomeHandler;

            AppDomain.Unload(ad);
        }

        static Assembly SomeHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            // some code would be here

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I was attempting to test the code on some dummy assemblies in a known location, some of which do/don't contain a valid imlementation/s. Is my code not amenable to unit testing or if it is, how can I avoid these exceptions? Thanks

Comment: Well-formed question, thanks for the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code is running in a different application base (NUnit's or Visual Studio's or whatever is running your test).  When you create a domain without specifying the base it uses the base of the application running your code, e.g. "Program Files\NUnit\Bin", and of course your assembly can't be found there.

The solution is to use the application base of your code when creating the `AppDomain`, which you can get from the current thread:

```
var callingDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
var setup = new AppDomainSetup 
            { 
                ApplicationBase = callingDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase 
            };

var ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("someName", null, setup);
```

[This blog post](http://timbar.blogspot.com/2011/10/wiping-state-clean-static-stateful.html) goes into a little more detail, but not much.  Still worth a read though.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I initially imagined I might need an IAppDomainFactory with this for the unit tests implementation and my original code for the production implementation, but seems like this is suitable for both as it just makes the search directory explicit?

Comment: Eh, it's a trade-off.  Having an `NUnitAppDomainFactory` might be a little more specific, but of course adds a little more complexity.  If you do use this for both I'd leave a big fat comment in the code as to why it's being done this way.